# .htaccess Rewrite Rules online and localhost

Tags: .htaccess

On this website and on wamp localhost

http://www.aproapetot.ro/page.php?categ_id=1&id=1

http://localhost/aproapetot-backup/page.php?categ_id=1&id=1

I tried to build the .htaccess, but without any success.

This is what I wrote for online website:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+).html$ page.php?categ_id=$1
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

and this for localhost

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /aproapetot-backup/
RewriteRule index.php index.html 
RewriteRule ^page-([0-9]+).html$ page.php?categ_id=$1
RewriteRule ^page\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

Someone please give a little help.

It's a website with jokes so after .ro/page.php?categ_id=1&id=1 I have a category(1) and subcategory(1).
I want to have like this 
.ro/jokes/doctors instead of how is now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want based upon the htaccess content, but what I do understand is that you want /jokes/doctors is rewritten to /pages.php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !pages.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pages.php [L]
```

The above code will rewrite all requests to pages.php, as long as:

- %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "!-f": The file itself does not exist on the server.
- %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !pages.php: The request is not made to pages.php (meaning that it already has been rewritten)

Finally you can use PHP to obtain the parameters using:

```
/* Get all parameters from the URL */
$_GET['path'] = rawurldecode( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
/* Remove double slashes and backslahses and convert all slashes and backslashes to '/' */
$_GET['path'] = preg_replace( array('#[/\\\\]+#', '/(\/\.)+(\/)/'), '/', $_GET['path']);


$_GET['path'][0] should contain "jokes"
$_GET['path'][0] should contain "doctors"
```

==edit==

Redirecting using htaccess (not the best method)

```
Redirect 301 /page.php?categ_id=6&id=0 /anecdotes
Redirect 301 /page.php?categ_id=1&id=1 /jokes/doctors
```

PHP (or other server side script). You can perform a check if the url is in fact having numbers (see `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`) and ifso, add some header redirection to your page.

```
<?PHP
header('Location: www.aproapetot.ro/' . $cat . '/' . $subcat );
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The website has more then one categories and subcategories. For ex this link

Comment: Thank you for answering. The website has more then one categories and subcategories. For ex this link    http://www.aproapetot.ro/page.php?categ_id=6&id=0 has category 6  and subcategory 0, meaning that the category is anecdotes and no subcategory. So in the database each number, categ and subcateg, has a name. I want with rewrite rules to bring that names instead on nrs. For ex: .ro/anecdotes, or .ro/jokes/sir john, or .ro/stories/funny stories, or .ro/stories/wise stories. All examples are categ and subcat that are in database, but in the link, after the page.php they show up like numbers.

Comment: I see what you are at. There is however one slight problem: .htaccess cannot communicate with your database. Thus, if you want .htaccess to handle this, you need to hardcode ALL numbers and names in the htaccess file. A better solution however would be to change the links on the website, so that the numbers dont show up anymore and use the above htaccess to rewrite the names to numbers. If you want to change the numbers to names per se, you could also use javascript for that. I'll edit my answere.

Comment: I read your answer and from yesterday I started to learn jquery :).